# process/application wise internet usage statistics on a machine in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know which of my currently running applications on my machine are using my internet bandwidth and upto what level are they using it (percentage of usage). I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630285/programmatically-getting-per-process-network-statistics-on-windows) but it is taking about TDI filter driver and such stuffs which I am not aware of as I am not such an expert in it. I am willing to understand it and develop it though. Please help me in understanding this and code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **Process Monitor** as a very useful tool and it served my purpose so I didnt had to write any code although i am yet to check out whether it gives any API which i can use in my application to get some information I need.

Thanks everyone for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone started a project already, possibly a good place to start:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemeter/

Comment: the application you have suggested only shows the internet usage of the machine in general i.e. how much bytes is getting downloaded/uploaded. I want the list of processes/applications in my machine which are using the internet for some kind of activity like downloading/uploading.